# Open Excel xlsx file for viewing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I need to open up an xlsx file so that the user can see it.

I used the following code but was not able to display the excel file:

```
public ActionResult GetExcelReport()
{
    string fileName = "Sheet1.xlsx";
    string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Test", fileName);

    return File(path, "application/xlsx");
}
```

I was hoping that the retrun `File(path ...`

would actually open up the file for viewing.

Comment: What happened? Also, your MIME type is wrong.

Comment: Nothing happened. No error. I also tried with application/xls but same thing. No error. Nothing happens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, and:

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
excel.Visible=true;
```

By the way, you can also use `using System.Diagnostics;`, and

```
Process.Start(path);
```

You just open a file stream via using `File`, it doesn't `Launch` a file.

Comment: Well, you can use `process.WaitForInputIdle();`

Comment: Meanwhile, you can also use `process.WaitForExit();`

Answer (score -1):

To expand on bhuang3's answer: if you want your user to be able to see the Excel spreadsheet and then have your application do something with it then I would use the Interop answer since your application can keep hold of the reference to perform actions.

You can open it with

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks xlWBs = xlApp.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook xlWB = xlWBs.Open(path);
xlApp.Visible = true;
```

After you've finished with it then you should close the workbook and quit the application to prevent Excel from hanging around headless in memory (which can have some very odd side effects when the user goes to open another spreadsheet on their machine)

```
xlWB.Close();
xlWB = null;
xlWBs = null;
xlApp.Quit();
xlApp = null;
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to open the spreadsheet and then give full control over to the user I would use the `Process.Start(path)` solution since it avoids a lot of the potentially messy COM issues.